# How to stop Magento requiring two product descriptions?

Tags: magento, require

I read [somewhere](http://robertsonandassociates.org.uk/2009/11/magento-product-description-read-more/) that you can stop Magento from requiring two product descriptions... this would suit me to the ground, since I'm adding a lot of products to our store that are just basic things with literally one-sentence descriptions and rather than duplicating the sentence to SE's annoynace or putting a full stop or whatever in one of the boxes, I'd like to disable them.

Does anyone know where to turn off requiring the full-descriptions? (Or short if not..)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a common request and I'm surprised it isn't documented yet.

In the menu *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes* click the entry for "Description". Change it's "Values Required" to "No" and save.

Comment: I had a client who would use `&nbsp;` as a workaround for hundreds of products. I couldn't bring myself to point out the obvious attribute change.